# Scala-Lift project in Eclipse Scala IDE errors

Tags: ide, scala, lift

I installed [Scala IDE for Eclipse](http://www.scala-ide.org/), and it seems to be working okay. So now I'm trying to import a Lift project (specifically -- autogenerated Lift project from [Stax application platform](http://stax.net/)), and now I'm having four errors at my workspace:

```
value net is not a member of package <root> Boot.scala /rss2lj/src/scala/bootstrap/liftweb line [3..6] Scala Problem
```

At lines:

```
import _root_.net.liftweb.util._
import _root_.net.liftweb.http._
import _root_.net.liftweb.sitemap._
import _root_.net.liftweb.sitemap.Loc._
```

Could anyone please help me out with it?

**UPD**: I found a [discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/5a9949763d2bc5f7/3271bd1a50ac2b07) with solution for maven-based projects, but the project, I'm trying to work with is not maven-based.

I got an answer [here](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user/browse_thread/thread/34fa2fa811622f08), but the new error occured on the same lines:

```
error while loading Helpers, Scala signature Helpers has wrong version 
 expected: 5.0 
 found: 4.1 in /home/gleontiev/workspace/rss2lj/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ 
lift-util-1.0.jar(net/liftweb/util/Helpers.class)

error while loading LiftRules, Scala signature LiftRules has wrong 
version 
 expected: 5.0 
 found: 4.1 in /home/gleontiev/workspace/rss2lj/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ 
lift-webkit-1.0.jar(net/liftweb/http/LiftRules.class)

error while loading Loc, Scala signature Loc has wrong version 
 expected: 5.0 
 found: 4.1 in /home/gleontiev/workspace/rss2lj/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ 
lift-webkit-1.0.jar(net/liftweb/sitemap/Loc.class)

error while loading Menu, Scala signature Menu has wrong version 
 expected: 5.0 
 found: 4.1 in /home/gleontiev/workspace/rss2lj/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/ 
lift-webkit-1.0.jar(net/liftweb/sitemap/Menu.class)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best place to ask questions like this is on the [Scala IDE user](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user) mailing list.