# Setting up a Scala Lift project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, classpath, lift

I'm trying to set up my first scala lift project in Eclipse and it is Not Simple (TM).

What I have done is set up the project trough Maven with the following

```
mvn archetype:generate -U \
-DarchetypeGroupId=net.liftweb \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=lift-archetype-basic_2.9.1 \
-DarchetypeVersion=2.4-SNAPSHOT \
-DarchetypeRepository=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \
-DgroupId=demo.helloworld -DartifactId=helloworld -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I then created an eclipse project from this with `mvn eclipse:eclipse` (because it's hellish to figure out all the dependencies, and add them all to the build path manually)

The project then conflicts with the installed Scala version. So I removed the three existing references to scalalang from the buildpath, and added my own scala to the buildpath. I'm using scala 2.9.0.

Now the project can be built, but when I try to run RunWebApp, an exception is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: RunWebApp
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RunWebApp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: RunWebApp. Program will exit.
```

I'm aware of the answer on [Scala-Lift project in Eclipse Scala IDE errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245715/scala-lift-project-in-eclipse-scala-ide-errors) suggesting to ask the question on  http://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user yet I hoped someone here could point me to the answer in a way someone else with the same problem might find the answer too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I advice you to use lift with sbt. You can find template project here https://github.com/viktortnk/lift-quickstart with sbt 0.11.2 and lift 2.4

It also includes sbt eclipse plugin to work in scala-ide.

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 3):

I find if you use sbt 0.11 and the sbteclipse plugin, it does all the magic for you.

https://github.com/harrah/xsbt

https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but it comes up in the search results pretty high, so I wanted to add an updated answer.

The latest Scala IDE (2.1 M3) is getting quite good, as are the maven integrations. I have an open-source demo project at:

https://github.com/awkay/lift_squeryl_demo

that gives instructions on getting eclipse set up with the following features:

- Simply Import a lift project based on this pom (which uses Scala 2.9/Lift 2.5) As "Existing Maven Project". Done. Nothing else to run. No sbt files to generate. No eclipse project files to generate...it just works.
- Great scala support, including highlights on implicits, great source level debugging
- Web tools server support (run/debug your webapp in the servers tab of eclipse)
- JRebel support for on-the-fly class reloading (there is a free license for this!)
- Typical maven support for command-line builds and packaging
- The ability to any number of Java webapps on the same tomcat instance, in cases where you have to deal with integration among apps.

The result is an experience that requires no command line interaction at all, and includes super-fast edit-save-reload web development. It really gives you the dynamic language development experience.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the problem you're having, but sometimes you need to make sure the Scala library appears *before* the JRE library in the project classpath (or run configuration used to execute it).

http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000119-classnotfoundexception-trying-to-run-scala-app-in-helios